# What is the practical difference between Graph.View.SetValueExt<>() and Graph.View.Cache.SetValueExt<>()?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I think I have a practical understanding of the role of the `cache`, but what are the differences between these two methods, and if there are major differences, when would one be better over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functional difference, the view just has a shortcut to the main dac's cache inside of it. Same with current: Graph.View.Current is the same as Graph.View.Cache.Current

Comment: This is probably another question, but since you brought it up, I can't find any good documentation on what 'current' is. I've seen it used in conjunction with a record update, and it seems to work without it. Is it necessary?